# Make control public in designer generated file

Tags: asp.net

It there any way to tell the ASP.NET `.designer.cs` code generator to create public controls instead of protected?

`.master.designer.cs` file:

```
/// <summary>
/// btnLanguageEN control.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Auto-generated field.
/// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
/// </remarks>
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton btnLanguageEN;
```

`.master` file:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnLanguageEN" OnClick="btnLanguageEN_Click" Text="ENG" />
```

Why I need it? I am trying to access to master page controls from child page:

`.aspx` file:

```
<%@ MasterType TypeName="www.MainMaster" %>
```

`.aspx.cs` file:

```
Master.btnLanguageEN.Text = "123";
```

Here I receive an error stating that `btnLanguageEN` is protected.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why do you need "public" control? I have a few suspicions but would like to hear what you are trying to accomplish to advise proper solution.

Comment: better practice would be to make a property which is accessible to set and get the text of that control - you don't want to expose the entire control for security and developer abuse reasons. It's one of many reasons why by default since ASP.NET 2.0 that its protected rather than public to encourage this behaviour and practice.

Comment: @Ahmedilyas, thank you. Have done this way already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a strongly typed reference to your master page by including this on your ASPX page.

```
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/Masters/Master1.master" %>
```

On your Master Page, create a property. This will make the control available from other classes..

```
public Button btnLanguageENMaster
{
    get {return btnLanguageEN;}
    private set;
}
```

Then from your regular page code behind you can do this...

```
Master.btnLanguageENMaster.Text = "Hello, world!"
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than modify the designer generated code, reference the control through the Page's `Master` property using the `FindControl` method.

You'll need to add the following directive to the top of your child page (if it's not already there) to reference the master page:

```
<%@ MasterType virtualpath="~/Masters/Master1.master" %>
```

Then, in your child page's code behind, you can do things like the following.

```
void Page_Load()
{   
   // Gets a reference to a LinkButton on the master mage.
   // a ContentPlaceHolder
   LinkButton mpLinkButton = (LinkButton) Master.FindControl("btnLanguageEN");
   if(mpLinkButton != null)
   {
       mpLinkButton.Text = "123 - Labelled by Child Page";
   }
}
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxwa0ff0.aspx

Comment: I know about `FindControl`,but I was curious maybe there is more elegant way to accomplish this... Okay, thank you.

Comment: I really dislike this answer. It's not strongly typed. If you change the name of btnLanguageEN, then your content page isn't going to be updated and you'll get a runtime error.